# Is it good or bad idea to use tor always?

Tags: security

Am I less or more secure, if I use tor when I do not need anonimity?

If a web site does not support https, and I need to download a program from there, is it better to use tor, or not?

Is it good idea to configure system to send [almost] all traffic through tor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Tor, not for hidden services, your exit node can know and do what normally your ISP can know and do. So if your ISP has no reason to mess with you, it is more secure to not use Tor. (Since you don't need anonymity.) Using https fixes this either way.

Regardless of Tor, if you don't use https, the ISP on the other side can also tamper with your data.

(Personally, I use Tor for casual browsing and to access hidden services, but not for logging in on personal accounts.)

Answer (score 0):

In general I think its preferred not to do bandwidth intensive tasks, usual examples would be torrenting or streaming (netflix/hulu). For general browsing you might be fine. Although I would say there are plenty of websites you are going to have troubles getting to due to blocking of exit nodes. Downloading from a site that uses http would pretty much result in the same process on either clearnet or tor, only difference I could see would be your IP would not be your own. As for safety if I understand correctly the vulnerabilities you open yourself up to when using http would not change between clearnet and tor. In general your questions are pretty broad. It might be best to do some more research so you can formulate questions that might elicit a more defined answer.

Answer (score 0):

Good Idea!

But you should have another one computer for personal life, with your real facebook account and e-mail. Clean, crystal you.

And use Tored machine like you are not you. Means, never use your real name, real ID, driver licence, credit cards.  Only shadow, only bitcoin, only Tor.